# setMediaAspectRatio(MediaAspectRatio.PORTRAIT) is not working Google ad manager

Tags: android, admob, ads, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I need to load a Portrait Full-screen native ad.

I have set the nativeAdOptions like these
`val nativeAdOptions = NativeAdOptions.Builder().setMediaAspectRatio(MediaAspectRatio.PORTRAIT).build()`

and load the ad like this

```
AdLoader.Builder(context, adUnitId).withNativeAdOptions(nativeAdOptions)
```

Even I set the `MediaAspectRatio` to `MediaAspectRatio.PORTRAIT`.
I am getting landscape ads.

Is there any issue with Google Ad Manager SDK or Do I need to specify any extra AdOptions?